# Id of the connection in Ratchet web socket requests

Tags: symfony, ratchet

I am testing Ratchet with Symfony. Tests are fine but I cannot understand where a property **`$conn->resourceID`** is coming from... Here is the code from the official tutorial

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

I cannot find it (**`$conn->resourceID`**), IDE cannot find it, but it works, it is populated somehow....

Does anyone has a clue to help me to understand?

Thanks

Comment: http://socketo.me/docs/server says : resourceId is An incremental number assigned when the connection is made (Added to each connection)

Comment: @johnSmith yes true, I saw that but I had to dig deeper into ```React\Socket\src\TcpServer.php```

the id is coming from a php command named ```stream_socket_server```